under sink connector leaking when moved, should I hire a pro?
the connection looks like a press fit. there is a small c clamp that prevents the collar from pressing downwards (up in the photo). I turned off the water and messed with it, I couldn't get it to come apart but it stopped leaking when water pressure was resumed.
makes me feel uneasy about this connection, not sure if I should consider changing it myself, leaving it alone or hiring a pro just for this one thing. recommendations?
pic: https://i.imgur.com/mAwmKSM.jpeg

We don't know anything about your DIY skills related to this problem, so we can only guess. I would say, with something important and potentially house-ruining like water leaks, if you're not sure your fix worked, get a pro. Long-term slow water damage can cause tens of thousands in repairs down the road.

I am lost on what a "wheb" is and if this question needs editing. I am thinking the OPs terminology needs some editing.

That is a "SharkBite" brand shut off valve. What you believe is a "C" clip is just a cover.
It seals with "O" rings and has a ring of clamping "teeth" that hold the pipe from being pulled out.
The pipe may not have been inserted all the way and your efforts cured that. Or there could have been a small piece of debris that was disallowing the seal and it got dislodged
Wiggle it gently and see if it starts to leak again. If it does it should be replaced.  The removal tool to separate the valve from the pipe is available where you buy the valves.
If it doesn't leak with a wiggle applied, keep an eye on it. To be safe maybe put a bowl under it.  If it doesn't start to leak again in a few days, you should be fine.

RMDman, thank you for making such a complete answer! I tested it out and after wiggling it a bit, it leaked again. So I turned off the water, compressed the fitting again and now its back to not leaking. The other end of this hose goes into the dish washer, so ideally I swap the fitting and not the entire hose (as it's less trouble than messing around in the back of the dish washer). Is this a standard part I can buy or are there a bunch of sizes and I need to figure out which one I have?
